# Magento 2.3 - Category Products indexer takes so much time although I have little products

Tags: magento2, indexer

I have just installed Magento 2 a few days ago.

And suddenly when I try to reindex manually I noticed that the `Category Products` indexer takes much time. **more than 8 mins**

And I've got this exception in `Sentry` about **2k** time

```
WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 
20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size 
or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the 
temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 
2160000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 2281701376 bytes.
```

from the exception above: I've updated the buffer pool size to max value allowed but the problem didn't solve.

Notes:

- I don't have so many products, It's just dummy data.
- I've updated to Magento 2.3.2 today but the problem still exists.
- I don't have this issue on my localhost domain.

Comment: try with php -d memory_limit=4096M indexer:reindex

Comment: Thanks but It doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Can you check if there is anything logged into log files in indexing process.

Comment: @nishu Yes, I've included the exception above

Comment: this is just a warning any error logged in log files.

Comment: @nishu this is the only issue in logs files.

Comment: I know anas has comment it but try this 
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento indexer:reindex
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: @Vijay-CyberLocker Doesn't solve the problem too, I think you all ignoring the warning, Allocated memory is more than 2 Gigabyte that's a very huge number especially with dummy data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experience with Magento, I've noted that disabled items cause this issue.

I've **deleted** all **disabled items** like **products, categories, store views and so on**

After that, this issue fully disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known bug of 2.3.2 specifically.

Happens if you have a lot of product attributes with `used_in_product_listing = 1`. Reducing the number of such attributes (by changing this corresponding value to 0 on some of them) seems to help somewhat:

> We have 97 attributes used in product listing. By removing just 6 of them, we reduce time to 6 minutes.

For reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23462

Comment: I have only 55 attributes and about 20 used in product listing.